# Compile Time Calculate Template Size

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor

I am trying to come up with a way let user to be able to set object pool size using a define,

```
#define POOL_SIZE 0.2
```

then during compilation do the following,

```
Pool<int,((POOL_SIZE * 1024)/sizeof(int))> pool;
```

Is this possible do this in a std98 compliant way? Compiler says not a constant expression.

Comment: That template argument is a double not an int, does it work if you wrap it with a static_cast<int> ?

Comment: @Borgleader thanks that worked I only tried c style cast not static

Answer (score 0):

You can change strategy a little bit and use

```
#define POOL_SIZE 512

Pool<int,((POOL_SIZE)/sizeof(int))> pool;
```

Answer (score 0):

compiling under clang gives the reason why:

```
./cexpr.cpp:36:10: error: conversion from 'double' to 'std::size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') is not allowed in a converted constant expression
pool<1024 * 0.2 / sizeof(int)> p;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The important words here being: *converted constant expression* because you are converting from a double to an (int? size_t?) during the template expansion. That's illegal.

It's a shame you don't have c++14 because this would be legal:

```
static constexpr std::size_t mypoolsize = 1024 * 0.2 / sizeof(int);
pool<mypoolsize> p;
```

(I am assuming that your poolsize template argument is a std::size_t)

Another (c++98) way is to clean up the macro so that the result of the conversion is coerced to be the correct type:

```
#define POOLSIZE(sz, factor) std::size_t(sz * factor / sizeof(int))
```

or maybe in your case...

```
#define POOLSIZE(sz, factor) int(sz * factor / sizeof(int))
```